# "There was an error processing the request" in w3wp process .Net

Tags: c#, .net, w3wp, worker-process, w3wp.exe

It is a .Net application.

I have been researching, but everything I have found was either related to Ajax or jQuery.
PLEASE NOTE that the error we saw here is **NOT** related to any Ajax or jQuery related operations. It is related to the .Net **w3wp** worker process.

**PROBLEM**:
Our customers reported that they are not able to Access the application and were getting this error.
Before the issue got redirected to us (developers), the level 1 support team recycled the Application Pools in IIS and the App was up & running.

On going through our error logs, we saw this error thrown multiple times during that interval:
"Message: **There was an error processing the request.**"

Here is the exception log:

---

Timestamp: 06/10/2015 04:42:02
Message: **There was an error processing the request.**
Additional Info: Stack_Trace[], Requested URL [], Browser[Chrome45], UserAuth[UserId[], UserName[], UserType[] ]
Category: Error&Warning
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:ERROR
Machine: xxxx
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130885704011364329
Process Id: 9940
Process Name: **c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe**
Win32 Thread Id: 10100
Thread Name: xxxx
Extended Properties: Transaction Id - xxxx

---

Please note that the error was getting caught for the same process every time: **c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe**

Could anyone please help me understand:

- What could have caused this issue?
- What could be the possible reasons?
- How could we handle this exception to avoid it in future?
- Any reference links to refer to?

Any form of help in figuring this issue out would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is that lovely bit of logging coming from, though? Have you checked if the event viewer contains more information (such as the exact stack trace of what's going wrong)?

Comment: This is the IIS worker process. It just mean something went wrong with the request. You will have to find out the request that is causing the error. Event Viewer or IIS Log around the same time might help. Also check the app pool recycle settings.

Comment: I checked the event viewer and it is clean during that time. 
There are no records for 10/6/2015 04:42 AM. 
However, I do see a couple of error logs at 04:43, and that was AFTER the "error processing the request" exception was caught.

Anyway, those errors were:
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated. 
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.